# SonarQube 8.9 doesn’t start, it’s blocked in loading page after login

Tags: linux, sonarqube, centos7, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube-web

i need help with SonarQube.
I’m trying to use the latest verions (8.9) on CentOS 7, i did all but i’m not able to see the main page because it gets stuck in the loading page after login.
There aren’t error in log file, the unique “error” that i found, if i inspect the source, is:
Application failed to start! SyntaxError: Unexpected token x in JSON at position 556.

Any suggest??

[image]

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem after time and time. It was so strange by the way after an accuratly check of the network i find the problem.
It was the firewall that blocked some request after login page, i hope this can help those in this same situation..

Answer (score -1):

This is a network issue. The firewall is blocking the sonarqube request

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30789917)